# Passing pointer to calling function but called function parameter as reference

Tags: c++

I have tried this piece of code mentioned below, I'm not understanding why `*p` need to be pass to `doOperation()` function. Why can't we pass `p`? What is the difference between the two?

```
doOperation(*p); // need explanation why derefencing
doOperation(p); // Gives compilation error
```

```
int main()
{
    int *p = getpointer();
    std::cout << "p:" << *p << std::endl;
    doOperation(*p); // Why this has to be pass as a pointer when the function parameter as reference
    return 0;
}

void doOperation(int &ptr) 
{
   //std::cout << "ptr:" << ptr << std::endl; 
}

int *getpointer()
{
    int *ptr = new int[10];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        *(ptr+i) = i;
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

Comment: `doOperation(*p); // Why this has to be pass as a pointer` That's not passing the pointer. `p` is the pointer, `*p` is the value pointed to, in this case an integer whose reference is passed. `for (i=0; i <= 10; i++)` This initializes 11 elements but the array was allocated with only 10.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared `p` as an integer pointer. The function `doOperation` takes an int reference as a parameter. `doOperation(*p)` means that you're dereferencing the pointer (which points to the first element in the array) and passing it to the function. Also as @dxiv have pointed out, in the function `getpointer`, the loop initializes 11 elements instead of 10. you can solve this by just changing `<=` to `<`.

If you want to pass the pointer by reference instead, the function `doOperation` can look like this:

```
void doOperation(int *&ptr)
{
    std::cout << "ptr:" << ptr << std::endl;
}
```

Then you can just pass the pointer as an argument like this:

```
doOperation(p);
```

Output:

```
p:0
ptr:0x2b71550
```

The code after the changes should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

void doOperation(int *&ptr)
{
    std::cout << "ptr:" << ptr << std::endl;
}

int *getpointer()
{
    int *ptr = new int[10];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        *(ptr+i) = i;
    }

    return ptr;
}

int main()
{
    int *p = getpointer();
    std::cout << "p:" << *p << std::endl;
    doOperation(p);
    return 0;
}
```